# PHP PDO file upload and save to MySQL database results in obscure file breakage

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo

After a lot of testing I have realised something is going wrong with my file upload process, and the resulting file(s) become mangled despite displaying the correct file details - size, name, mime type etc. After a LOT of testing and trying different options I've realised this problem is not an extraction/display error as I had first thought. It is definitely breaking somewhere subtly during the upload/DB insertion process. The file is saved into a medium blob MySQL field that has a BINARY attribute. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong in my code for handling the upload/storage process? I get no errors at all.

```
 <form action="./app.fileUpload.php?lnk=<?=$lnk?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5632000">
 <label for='file'>Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <input class="button" style="margin-top: 12px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" title="Upload">
 </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $temp = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extn = strtolower(end($temp));
        if(($extn == "doc") || ($extn == "docx") || ($extn == "pdf")) {
            // Filetype is correct. Check size
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 5632000) {
                // Filesize is below maximum permitted. Add to the DB.
                $mime = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $tmpf = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

                try {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $database.appFiles (`appID`, `uaID`, `uID`, `dateUploaded`, `applicationKey`, `fileName`, `fileMime`, `fileSize`, `file`)
                    VALUES
                    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                    // Bind Values
                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
                    $stmt->bindParam(2, $uaID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
                    $stmt->bindParam(3, $uID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
                    $stmt->bindParam(4, time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
                    $stmt->bindParam(5, $applicationKey, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
                    $stmt->bindParam(6, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
                    $stmt->bindParam(7, $mime, PDO::PARAM_STR, 128);
                    $stmt->bindParam(8, $size, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
                    $stmt->bindParam(9, $file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

                    // Execute the query
                    $stmt->execute();
                } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }

            } else {
                // Filesize is over our limit. Send error message
                $error = "Your file is too large. Please read the instructions about file type and size, above.";
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Your file was the incorrect type. Please read the instructions about file type and size, above.";
        }
    }
?>
```

**EDIT** Database info is called by including a file at the top of the page. The file looks like this:

```
<?php
// DATABASE SETTINGS
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "nameinhere";
$password = "passwordinhere";
$database = "dbnamehere";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

    // close the database connection
    //$conn = null;

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: The table name needs to be a `?` param. You can't insert variables directly into PDO (to stop mysql injection).

Comment: Hmm, all my table names are either basic text names (like this one) or $values. I've never had a problem with table names, but thank you, I will read up more about this and modify my habits accordingly.

Comment: Basic text should work. I meant you could not use variables  (`$database.appFiles`).

Comment: I'm not following you clearly. Are you suggesting that my use of $database should be replaced by ? and a matching $stmt->bindParam(1, $database, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16); be set up specifically for it?

Comment: That is what I am saying. If your still having problems, turn on PDO error reporting.

Comment: I'm not clear on the correct syntax to make that particular change correctly, so to test the idea I just changed the $database to the plain text value but this has make no difference to the result at all.

Comment: Try adding `$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` below your database connection to display errors. I had a similar problem recently and this worked.

Comment: Please check my edit on the main section - DB info is now shown. Already had the error display code there but I don't believe it is working correctly...!

Comment: I can't find an error (though I'm no PHP expert). The only thing I would say is to echo out your `$_POST`/`$_FILES` variable and see if they are submitted. If you are using Chrome, check to see if your variables are redirected via 301. Also try marking out parts of your code, and seeing if the other parts work (i.e. basic debugging).

Comment: Thanks Krii. I've done most of that already, the file is successfully reaching the DB and is inserted all ok, it's just getting "mangled" slightly somewhere along the way. I suspect it's just a handling error during the upload/save sequence.

Comment: There's a very common and proven technique for file uploads - you upload a file to the file system, and store its path in database. That's fast, accurate, easier to maintain and read. You're doing the whole process wrong since the beginning.

Comment: @bad_boy That's a subjective matter. MySQL can succssfully handle files uploaded into it. It has the function to do so, built in. I don't really want to store a few thousand files that need to be kept for a minimum of 3 years, in a directory. That is messy, and immensely laborious for backup purposes. A single DB dump is far more effective. There is no valid reason why storing files inside a DB is bad.

Comment: @Cassandra You're not the first person who faced this task. This task has been already solved 1000 times before by another developers. And all beginners ask this question every day here. And yeah, by the way where MySQL stores its data? Right, it stores its data on the file-system. So when uploading a `blob-like-type` you anyway upload it to the file-system. So in your case you upload, it to file-system, then again read it from file-system by issuing `SELECT` query. MySQL (just like as random db out there including No-SQL solutions) surely can handle since it's a bunch of text.

Comment: Just for a second, image if you had to store images of different dimensions for some kind of e-commerce system. When doing it right, you upload several resized images to the file system, while storing only file's base name in database. But what if you were uploading them all a database? That's gonna bite. Also, it's easy to hack your script. I can rename some dangerous to something that has `pdf` extension, and then rename and execute it

Comment: Those are some fairly large claims there - there is no way to upload a pdf and then rename it from inside the DB. However this is now very off topic. The question is why is my efforts breaking. Please respond back if you have a relevant answer. Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't want to listen, It's all done here. As for there's "no way to hack you script", read this (Double extensions (part 2)): https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/

Comment: @bad_boy Thanks for that, however your section "It's all done here" does not link to anything at all. Error? As far as the security issue you have pointed out, even if we assume that all of the other layers of security I have in place that you don't see from me specifying the section that deals with my query specifically - and there are several - even uploading a false .pdf can only result in it being pulled back down and delivered to the browser again. No name change is possible from within the DB. And no execution is possible. This has been interesting but not helped with the main question.

Comment: You haven't understood my points at all and you don't get it. So, to be specific to your question, your problem here is that, when requesting a file's contents from a database, its treated as a plain text and therefore its displayed as *mangled*. To make it display the way you want, you gotta call `header('Content-type: .....')` before you output that file content.   If you want a guarantee that file isn't damaged before you upload it, there's a specific pre-defined key which is called `error ` in $_FILES superglobal. `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ /* do the rest */ }`

Comment: @bad_boy Thanks again however like I've already said, the error is happening on the file upload side, NOT the download and display. I'm aware of how to do that and am already doing it perfectly fine. I've also already stated there are NO ERRORS in the upload process. I have added your suggestion and it has made absolutely no difference in behaviour or result. As per everything else, thanks but it's off topic. I don't want to waste time explaining or justifying my question or reasons for doing it this way. SO is not for that. There are reasons for this decision. Please respect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things eventuated, there actually was no problem at all with my PHP. It was prevented from working by a setting on the dev server, and it worked perfectly without any code change on the production server when tested under a hidden subdomain.

Thanks to all who attempted to help on this.

C